# show hide divs if user connected to facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to show/hide some links and some data on code ignitor website, based on the user login with facebook. This will need page reload after user logs in/logs out of facebook. How can i accomplish it? (i have been able to connect to fb and to apply checks if user is login/logout of my app)

Answer (score 0):

This is general approach, since i am not seeing your code, i ll try to explain you the process how you can acomplish it.

- after user has been authorised, you will set param in auth entity that he is from FB.
- in your Controller/View, you should be able to get that param, so if its true, simply in your view /js do something like this:

  if ($your_param) ? $('#wanna_hide').hide() : $('#wanna_hide').show();

Specificaly for CI, i am not sure, but this is just idea how you can make it.

Cheers! :)